# What's the best way to visualize load testing results

Tags: data-visualization, dataset, experiment-design

I have a piece of code that I'm adding a feature onto, and I need to test performance before and after the feature addition. So I used a test instance with a large amount of data and triggered the endpoint with and without my feature (flag on and flag off) and now I have a data set with the elapsed times as follows: (The same endpoint was called 100 times parallely for each flag value):

| Flag off | Flag on |
| --- | --- |
| 32412 | 24568 |
| 28550 | 22996 |
| 26574 | 25395 |
| 35558 | 21346 |
| ...... | ..... |

What is the best way to show a comparison between the elapsed times? The purpose is to show there was no regression with the flag on.

If there was a better way to conduct the pexperiment, what would it be?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution depends on whether the values in each column are paired or not.

If paired, a scatterplot with a 1:1 line would be best. Depending on the data distribution, you may want to use some transparency for the points or even consider using a hexbin plot instead.

If unpaired, a split violin plot, or overlapping density plots with some transparency would be good options.